# OpenStreetMap-based geocoding/geolocation/maps/places API

Tags: api, geo-location, openstreetmap, google-maps, geocoding

I am currently using google maps in my web and mobile applications, but want to switch to an OSM alternative. The following services are the ones I use with gmaps:

[image]

I need an OSM provider that can offer me the same, and has a **license for commercial use**.

I found two already, mapbox.com and agilogik.de, but I still am not sure what exactly I need.

For web I will use leafletJS as my framework, but I still need one for iOS and android (one that supports both like google)

Comment: Are you OK with using different services, for instance one for geocoding and one for geolocation? Probability that you will find a single service providing all of this is low.

Comment: What is your budget? For instance 10 EUR per month or 1000 EUR per month?

Comment: I rejected the OSM solution due to the huge slow. Gmaps is the best but the new prices are abusive. I agree with you, is necessary an alternative...

Comment: @NicolasRaoul pricing is not a priority, but it should be realistic, and just do the same stuff gmaps did, but I think 8000 euro anually is my limit

If it's possible to use multiple services then I guess it can work

Comment: @Josem are you still using gmaps? Or did you find better solution

Comment: To improve your question's searchability, please remove the image and replace it with text. Also, please detail exactly what features it should offer. Do not just ask "alternative to Gmaps" because asking for alternatives is off-topic here. Please read https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48/how-to-ask-for-an-alternative-to-some-software and rewrite your requirements so that they are understandable even by someone who has never heard about Gmaps (but is knowledgeable in geocoding/etc). Thanks and good luck, this has the potential to become a great question! :-)

Comment: Yes @SuperUser, I suggest you to use OSM only for geocoding and in the meanwhile we find another solution the cheaper maps (native)https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/

Answer (score 3):

Give us a shot at [UnwiredLabs](https://unwiredlabs.com) and [LocationIQ](http://locationiq.com). We've got geolocation, geocoding and Maps APIs.

- For cellular + WiFi geolocation, we've got our own proprietary datasets
- For geocoding, we use a bunch of open-source datasets
- For maps, we use OSM tiles

P.S If it wasn't obvious, I work at unwiredlabs/ locationIQ. ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I like your pricing.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot out there, so I'll list a few I know or have used personally.

Full map stack services:

- [Mapbox](https://mapbox.com): Excellent hosted tiles, geocoding, routing, more. Uses open data as well as proprietary data. This can improve the quality of their results but also comes with usage limitations. Predictable pay-as-you-go pricing but can get expensive at higher usage levels.
- [Jawg.io](https://www.jawg.io) offers map tiles, geocoding, and routing based on open-data. Based in Paris so a great option for an European focus.

Tiles:

- [Stadia Maps](https://stadiamaps.com/) Very customizable hosted map tiles based on OSM

Geocoding services:

- [geocode.earth](https://geocode.earth) offers hosted geocoding services including really fast autocomplete using multiple open-data sources including OSM
- [Gisgraphy](https://www.gisgraphy.com/) hosted geocoding based on open-source supporting multiple open-data sources including OSM
- [Geocode.xyz](http://geocode.xyz/) Geocoding and geoparsing (pretty powerful) as a hosted service.
- [OpenCage geocoder](https://opencagedata.com/) Provides geocoding using Nominatim and several other geocoders, combined into one nice package
- [geocod.io](https://www.geocod.io/) really easy to use batch geocoding using open data for USA/Canada

Open source projects/self-hosted solutions:

- [Pelias geocoder](https://pelias.io) Open-source geocoder based on Elasticsearch. Very customizable and supports lots of open data sources out of the box. Can also use your own data
- [Nominatim](https://www.nominatim.org/) *The* OSM geocoder. If searching OSM data specifically is important to you, Nominatim is a great choice.
- [Photon open-source project](https://github.com/komoot/photon) Elasticsearch based autocomplete geocoding using OSM data. Works well with, or independently of, Nominatim
- [Geocode.xyz AMI](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B06Y1DVR9L) Amazon Machine Image to get started quicky with the Geocode.xyz geocoder in your own Amazon account

Additional resources:

- [OSM Wiki Search Engines page](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Search_engines)
- [Geocoder comparison website](http://getlon.lat/)

Disclaimer: I am a core contributor to Pelias and co-founder of geocode.earth. I mostly only know about geocoding, hence the focus here.